# «Проверьте текст на ошибки (срочно!)», «Расставить запятые (быстро!)» и проч.: уместны или нет?

Tags: обсуждение, faq

На сайте нередко задаются вопросы, в которых порой нет самого вопроса или даже просьбы. Например, такие:

> ### Срочно расставить запятые
>
> Вася шел с машей за ручку лил сильный дождь и падал снег.

или

> ### Проверьте на ошибки
>
> *Тут — мемуары на полторы страницы.*

Вообще, ресурс был создан не для таких заданий, а для создания библиотеки «подробных ответов на любые вопросы о русском языке» (см. [Тур](https://rus.stackexchange.com/tour)), но, к сожалению или счастью, некоторые участники выполняют все требования, выдвинутые пользователями-анонимами, часто даже не удосуживающимися отметить галочкой полезный ответ. Правильно ли это?

Предлагаю установить: быть таким вопросам или не быть — и занести установленное в [правила](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Нужно ли отвечать на бесконечное количество частных вопросов, получить ответ на которые можно самому, стоит только залезть в обычный справочник? Ведь далеко не факт, что они — эти частные вопросы — помогут другим людям.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такие вопросы нужно редактировать. Во-первых, нужно **уточнить у автора, что именно у него вызывает затруднение. Предложить автору попробовать самому ответить на свой вопрос.**
Во-вторых, если автор отреагировал, нужно **изменить заголовок вопроса** на тот пункт правил, который помогает выполнить задание (например, *"Запятые в сложном придаточном предложении"*), затем **исправить ошибки автора**. Тогда автор получит ответ, следующий пользователь, который будет искать информацию по этому пункту правил, придёт на наш сайт и получит пример использования правила, а наша база знаний наполнится.
Если автор не удосужился потрудиться, то нужно сделать то же самое - исправить заголовок и написать ответ - но через значительное время, когда задание будет уже не актуально для автора. Например, через неделю, 10 дней... Когда найдётся желающий ответить.

Полностью мы от таких вопросов не уйдём. Они встречаются на всех тематических Q&A сайтах. Я считаю, что в том виде, в котором они у нас сейчас имеются, им на сайте не место. Они бесполезны и только создают хаос в ленте вопросов. Если хотя бы заголовки будут конкретными, то к ним будет легче попасть из поиска, а значит, тот, кто ищет информацию по конкретной теме, найдёт наш сайт и, возможно, останется здесь.
Я считаю, что автору нужно помочь, а не делать работу за него.

Answer (score 2):

Эти вопросы о русском языке? Да. Вас смущает отсутствие вопросительного знака, тогда можно переформулировать в "Есть ли здесь ошибки?", хотя не вижу в этом необходимости. Другое дело, что нужно отличать школьные и студенческие задания, от реальных проблем, могущих возникнуть и человека.

Во втором случае, считаю, что нужно помочь, так как зачастую разобраться с конкретной пунктуацией, без специалиста довольно тяжело. Одна из причин, по которой я пришёл на этот форум, как раз подтянуть свои "запятые" до приемлемого уровня. Если же гнать всех подозрительных новичков, то боюсь форум проживёт недолго. Большая часть ответов на вопросы про этимологию - это копипаста Фасмера или Шанского с комментариями, их тоже удалять надо, ведь эти сведения выходят по первым ссылкам любого поисковика?

Другое дело, если явное домашнее задание. Тогда вопрос следует закрыть, предложив автору самому предоставить решение, а пользователи его проверят и при необходимости укажут на ошибки. На прошлом адресе даже существовал стандартный комментарий что-то типа:

> Согласно правилам форума, мы не выполняем домашние задания, а просим предложить свой вариант ответа, который потом исправим в случае необходимости

[Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430333/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%95), кстати, совсем недавний пример "хорошего" вопроса из домашнего задания.

Comment: Вы не различаете то, что действительно может пригодиться для библиотеки ответов (этимологию), пусть даже Фасмер и Шанский есть в интернете, и то, что навряд ли может помочь другим людям, т. е. по сути кроме как для конкретного человека не нужно. + как вы разбираетесь, где дз, а где недз? У вас выработаны критерии? Потому что существенной разницы между "расставить запятые" и "выполнить тест" я не вижу. Автор просто копирует задание из сборника в каждом случае, никак не выражая свое мнение.

Comment: И да: "выполнить тест" -- тоже о русском языке.

Comment: Различаю. Но не вижу причин, по которым помощь одному конкретному человеку менее важна, чем мифических помощь человечеству. Рассматривая множество частных случаев, человек понимает общие правила. Д/з же легко определить по специфическим текстам,  вне домашнего задания мало кто будет спрашивать о запятых у Толстого и пр. классиков, и однотипности предложений и орфограм.

Comment: то есть вы предлагаете определять дз по авторам текста? Хорошо, понятно.